# What military satellites are passing over Antarctica

Tags: orbit, military

I need to know what satellites pass over the South Pole (Antarctica) especially military.

Comment: A satellite that passes over the south pole should pass over the north pole too.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Exactly over South Pole - none one of satellites passes. It's not a useful orbit, compared with Sun-synchronous orbit.

Answer (score 8):

Anything with an inclination of more than 60 degrees (Well, between 60-120 degrees) will pass over Antarctica. That happens to be a lot of satellites! Anything in a Sun-synchronous orbit will, among others.

Just to name a few that are still orbiting, EXPLORER 36, ST5-A (And B and C), OV1-19, and many, many others.

Easiest way to find this might be to use https://heavens-above.com/main.aspx , and put in a locations in Antarctica.

Answer (score -4):

Um, ALMOST ALL OF THEM. Military satellites of the superpowers reserve the right to any possible theater of warfare. This implies an orbit that covers any sea (for the Navy), seashore (for their Marines), and land too (Army, AF). Since Antarctica covers nontrivial latitudes, a standard Sun-Synchronous Orbit (~97 degrees inclination, depending) covers Antarctica.

If there are any exceptions, they may be high enough in altitude that the antenna or sensor can use its slant range (e. g., GPS). Or they’re there to communicate with other satellites, not the surface and true polar coverage is redundant- again, slant range will do (no airmass loss from slant of view).

The extra cost of highly-inclined LEO just isn’t that bad these days. Meanwhile, not leaving an enemy any loopholes is considered worthy. Therefore ‘the military’ (NRO falls outside of the DoD) just goes for the extra inclination.